# filter xsl based on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

this is a snippet from my xml file

```
     <uformrecord>
          <state>Submitted</state>
          <created>2012-06-19T11:31:54</created>
          <updated>2012-06-19T11:32:13</updated>
          <id>53225sas3c1-d727-42cd-93a6-97cd778e5ee9</id>
          <ip>123.45.3.60</ip>
          <pageid url="/blah.aspx" name="Vacancy Application">1873</pageid>
          <memberkey emaillogin=""></memberkey>
          <fields>

            <ifyouhavetickedyeshowwouldyoudescribeyourdisabilitytickallthatapplytoyou record="532253c1-d727-42cd-93a6-97cd778e5ee9" sortorder="1" pageindex="2" fieldsetindex="0">
              <key>73b9150d-c65c-4ec0-9c8f-8d334b0495bf</key>
              <fieldKey>07a8ade7-ae13-41e6-bc3a-fe8444bcf9b0</fieldKey>
              <caption>If you have ticked 'Yes', how would you describe your disability (Tick all that apply to you.)</caption>
              <datatype>String</datatype>
              <values>
                <value key="c6de1932-9bba-4691-b19e-a44b5bb68c6c">I have a hearing problem</value>
                <value key="dd902bdb-89d7-4f14-ab60-4e69e803f321">I use a wheelchair</value>
                <value key="322c8e15-f722-406c-9d10-1769a2fb306e">I am dyslexic</value>
              </values>
            </ifyouhavetickedyeshowwouldyoudescribeyourdisabilitytickallthatapplytoyou>

    <anotherfieldblaf record="532253c1-d727-42cd-93a6-97cd778e5ee9" sortorder="1" pageindex="1" fieldsetindex="0">
              <key>73b9150d-c65c-4ec0-9c8f-8d334b0495bf</key>
              <fieldKey>07a8ade7-ae13-41e6-bc3a-fe8444bcf9b0</fieldKey>
              <caption>If you have ticked 'Yes', how would you describe your disability (Tick all that apply to you.)</caption>
              <datatype>String</datatype>
              <values>
                <value key="c6de1932-9bba-4691-b19e-a44b5bb68c6c">I have a hearing problem</value>
                <value key="dd902bdb-89d7-4f14-ab60-4e69e803f321">I use a wheelchair</value>
                <value key="322c8e15-f722-406c-9d10-1769a2fb306e">I am dyslexic</value>
              </values>
            </anotherfieldblaf>
.
.
.
.//many more fields
          </fields>
        </uformrecord>
```

Im using xpath like this to get fields.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$records//fields/child::*">
```

This returns all fields, however i want to only get the fields where the pageindex=2 for the field.

How can i do it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="$records//fields/child::*[@pageindex='2']">
```

Comment: thanks, was along the right lines but was putting the square brackets in the wrong place.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly specify the child:: axis. It is the default axis. After all, why would you specify it for * but not for fields. The inconsistency has no value.